# How to connect a wxWidgets timer to an event using wxEvtHandler::Connect

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been trying to connect my timer to an a function.
In my derived class
What i am doing is

```
Timer->SetOwner(this,wxID_Timer);
Timer->Connect(wxID_Timer,wxTimerEventHandler( Window::OnUpdate ), NULL, this );
```

Where my declaration of OnUpdate is

```
void OnUpdate( wxTimerEvent& event );
```

Can any one tell me what is wrong here, why is  OnUpdate not being called periodically after i start the timer?.
Please and Thank you.

Also I am not using static event Tables.The other answer on wxTimer is not helping me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of searching i actually found the answer, no one is answering so i am posting it here.
There were a few things that i was doing wrong.
i. I actually had to connect the class to my timer . That meant i had to do something like

```
this->Connect(Timer.GetId(),wxEVT_TIMER,wxTimerEventHandler( Window::OnUpdate ), NULL, this );
```

Where wxEVT_TIMER was the event type.

Similarly to disconnect

```
this->Disconnect(wxID_Timer,wxEVT_TIMER,wxTimerEventHandler( Window::OnUpdate ), NULL, this );
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be some confusion here so let me try to clear it.

You can *either* call `timer->Connect(...)` on the timer itself *or* use `SetOwner(frame)` and then do `frame->Connect(...)`.

Calling `SetOwner()` and then calling `Connect()` on the timer doesn't make much sense as `SetOwner()` ensures that the timer event is delivered to the owner directly. However by default there is no owner and the timer sends the events to itself which is why without `SetOwner()` call you must call `Connect()` on the timer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer did not work for me.  This is what I did instead.

You first must let your frame own the events that the wxtimer emits.

```
m_timer.SetOwner( this );
```

Then you can have your frame's event handler handle the events.
If you only have one timer, use this.

```
this->Connect( wxEVT_TIMER, wxTimerEventHandler( Frame::OnTimer ), NULL, this );
```

If you have multiple timers, use this to connect each timer's event to a different function.

```
this->Connect( m_timer.GetId(), wxEVT_TIMER, wxTimerEventHandler( Frame::OnTimerForSpecificTimer ), NULL, this );
```

Doing this will allow the frame to put the timer event in its event queue and process it when it can.